# Angular 4 call service method with data from previous service method call

Tags: angular, observable

I'm currently learning Angular while building a site that's meant to present results from fencing matches in real time as they are input from a desktop competition manager application.

I'm having problems with how to "chain" observable subscriptions. 
I've made it work but I'm pretty sure there has to be a more elegant solution.

When I route to a match i pass in the Id to get the match, like

```
getMatch(id: number){
    this._matchService.getMatch(id).subscribe
    (
      match => this.match = match,
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    )
```

The problem arises from the fact that the match object contains the Ids from the pool, competition and fencers in the match. So I need to use the response from getMatch to get competition, fencers and pool.

I'm currently doing it like this, but it doesn't feel very good.
I'm considering rebuilding the API do deliver all needed data in one call, but I'd like to make this work.

```
getMatch(id: number){
    this._matchService.getMatch(id).subscribe(
      match => {
        this.match = match;

        this._fencerService.getFencer(match.blueFencerId).subscribe(
          bf => this.blueFencer = bf,
          error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );

        this._fencerService.getFencer(match.redFencerId).subscribe(
          rf => this.redFencer = rf,
          error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );

        this._poolService.getPool(match.poolId).subscribe(
          pool => {
            this.pool = pool.name;

      this._competitionService.getCompetition(pool.competitionId).subscribe(
              comp => this.competitionName = comp.name
            )
          },
          error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        )
      },
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    )
  }
```

Also, this is what the matchService method looks like, with is the recurring pattern for the other services aswell:

```
getMatch(id: number): Observable<IMatch>{
  return this.getPopulatedMatches().map((matches: IMatch[]) => 
     matches.find(p => p.id === id));
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing something fundamentally wrong in my design, but I'd like to atleast split all the service calls into separate methods, somthing like.

```
ngOnInit() {
   getMatch();
   getPool(match.poolId);
   this.redFencer = getFencer(match.redFencerId);
   this.blueFencer = getFencer(match.blueFencerId);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested .subscribe() blocks are an anti-pattern.

Try this:

For rxjs > 5.5.2:

```
  getMatch(id: number) {
    const match$ = this._matchService.getMatch();

    const blueFencer$ = match$.pipe(
      flatMap(({ blueFencerId }) => this._matchService.getFencer(blueFencerId)),
    );

    const redFencer$ = match$.pipe(
      flatMap(({ redFencerId }) => this._matchService.getFencer(redFencerId)),
    );

    const pool$ = match$.pipe(
      flatMap(({ poolId }) => this._poolService.getPool(poolId)),
    );

    const competition$ = pool$.pipe(
      flatMap(({ competitionId }) =>
        this._competitionService.getCompetition(competitionId),
      ),
    );

    return { match$, blueFencer$, redFencer$, pool$, competition$ };
  }
```

For rxjs < 5.5.2:

```
  getMatch(id: number) {
    const match$ = this._matchService.getMatch();

    const blueFencer$ = match$
      .flatMap(({ blueFencerId }) => this._matchService.getFencer(blueFencerId));

    const redFencer$ = match$
      .flatMap(({ redFencerId }) => this._matchService.getFencer(redFencerId));

    const pool$ = match$
      .flatMap(({ poolId }) => this._poolService.getPool(poolId));

    const competition$ = pool$
      .flatMap(({ competitionId }) =>
        this._competitionService.getCompetition(competitionId));

    return { match$, blueFencer$, redFencer$, pool$, competition$ };
  }
```

Then in your component you can subscribe to each individual stream and do whatever you want.

Edit: 
If you want the streams to be created inside the `MatchService`:

```
export class MatchService {
  match$ = this.getMatch();

  blueFencer$ = this.match$.pipe(
    flatMap(({ blueFencerId }) => this.getFencer(blueFencerId)),
  );

  redFencer$ = this.match$.pipe(
    flatMap(({ redFencerId }) => this.getFencer(redFencerId)),
  );

  pool$ = this.match$.pipe(
    flatMap(({ poolId }) => this._poolService.getPool(poolId)),
  );

  competition$ = this.pool$.pipe(
    flatMap(({ competitionId }) =>
      this._competitionService.getCompetition(competitionId),
    ),
  );

  constructor(
    private _poolService: PoolService,
    private _competitionService: CompetitionService,
  ) {}

  getMatch(id: number): Observable<any> {
    // ...
  }

  getFencer(id: number): Observable<any> {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Only thing, and this is nit-picky because I am certain the OP would figure this out: `pool$` calls `getFencer` and it should be `getPool`.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Your code goes in the match.service, right?
I don't completely understand this line:
    const match$ = this._matchService.getMatch();

Comment: I've edited my question to show the solution with streams inside the match.service.  `const match$ = this._matchService.getMatch();` `match$`, stores the reference to the stream returned by `.getMatch()` method. I've created this variable simply to avoid repeating `this._matchService.getMatch();` all of the time.

Comment: Could you consider accepting this as an answer? Creating the code samples takes a lot of time and I think this answers the question.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Sorry! 
I got it working after a bit of trial and error. Thanks a lot for the help!